# Cell background image mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell in a `UITableView` that has an image as a background using the `colorWithPatternImage`. I would like to set a mode on this image to fit the cell, i.e. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, etc. (I'll go through and find the best one for my use)

Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
                                                                                                      *)indexPath
{
    if((indexPath.row)==1)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeScreen-buttons.jpg"]];

}
```

So how can I edit my code to add what I need? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `contents` of the cell's layer, try this:

```
cell.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeScreen-buttons.jpg"].CGImage;
```